# Flex mobile App - how to share data between apps

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, data-sharing

how do you share data between apps with a Flex mobile app?

For example, on Shazam, you can share the tag info -  you click the 'share' button, and it lists a number of apps to share the tag with, for example: 'add to dropbox', 'copy to clipboard', 'gmail', 'messaging', 'skype', 'wikitude myWorld'.

when you copy to clipboard, it sends this string:

'I just used Shazam to discover Stay by Rihanna, http:// .....'

What permissions do I need to give my Flex mobile app in order for shazam to list it as an app to send data to?

And when it does have permission, how do I receive that character string?

thanks,
steve

Comment: Not possible by default in AIR. You'll need to build/find an AIR Native Extension to allow this.

Comment: What is Apple's terminology for this called? data sharing? is it a permission?

Comment: No, it's not a permission. You need to use native (Java/Objective-X) code for it. In iOS, there is a "Share" menu and an "Open In" menu. Android simply has the Share menu